# How do I remove the trailing time zeros after the Date

Tags: views, webforms

I'm using Drupal 8.4 Webform Module. I selected the Date element (not Date/time). In the Webform Date Settings, I'm using date picker, Medium date - D, m/d/Y (Mon, 11/27/17). (I also tried Custom, D, M j, Y.

I'm using this field in a View, Format = Default medium date and this is what I get, Thu, 12/14/2017 - 00:009:00 AMFri, 12/15/2017 - 00:005:00 PM
. How do I remove the trailing zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Go to '**yoursite/admin/config/regional/date-time**' and click the button, '**+ Add Format**' to add a new date format.

Enter a name for this new format and add your date format in the Format string box.

Example: **D, M j, Y** will output **Fri, Dec 22, 2017**. Click **Add Format**

Go to your Webform > build and select the date element you want format with your new date format. In the Advanced tab, select your new date format in the SUBMISSION DISPLAY > SINGLE ITEM > ITEM FORMAT box and save.

You should also be able to select the new date format in Views.

Its best to clear the cache at **yoursite/admin/config/development/performance**